# How to telnet device OS XR and ping test

Tags: python

I cannot telnet device OS XR Cisco to ping test.
Please help me?
#Output:

D:\MY WORK\DTS_file\TOOL PING>python Ping_list.py
Node 1 -Checking IP Address 10.53.X.X

Cannot connect via Telnet to Station, may be node DOWN

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\MY WORK\DTS_file\TOOL PING\Ping_list.py", line 36, in 
show = (connection.send_command('ping vrf LRAN'+ ip1 ))
^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'connection' is not defined

```
import netmiko
import csv
import datetime
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler


nodenum = 1
f=open('ip_telnet.csv','r')
c=f.readlines()
f1=open('list_ping.csv','r')
dump = f1.readlines()

with open('report.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(['SHOW'])

    for i in c:
        print ("Node", nodenum, "-Checking IP Address", i)
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            connection=netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip=i, device_type="cisco_xr_telnet", username="xxx", password="xxx123", timeout=120)
        except:
                print('Cannot connect via Telnet to Station, may be node DOWN')
                print("")
                now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                nodenum = nodenum + 1
                logf = open("error.log", "a")
                logf.write(now)
                logf.write(" - Cannot connect via Telnet to ")
                logf.write(i)
                logf.close()
                continue
                
    for ip1 in dump:
        show = (connection.send_command('ping vrf LRAN'+ ip1 ))
        time.sleep(2)
        print(show)     
 
        write.writerow([show])
        print ("\n")
        
    f.close()
```

(https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Your blanket `except` allows the code to continue even when it could not connect. You are not setting `connection` to anything in the `except` branch so, like the error message says, it is unset. Code which cannot proceed shouldn't. Getting rid of critical errors by ignoring them is just inviting new problems.